# Composition of permutation: Online calculator Versus my Textbook "Abstract Algebra for Secondary Mathematics Teachers"

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book has I quote

"Notation 29. Given permutations *A* and *B* , instead of writing *A o B* we
write the shorthand notation: *AB*  [...] we refer to it as the product of *A* and *B* . "

But when I used those online calculator such as *WOLFRAMALPHA* to verify my work they understand that *A o B* is BA.

Which one is correct?

Comment: $AB$ always means $A\circ B$. But the meaning of the latter can be one of two things, depending on convention.

Answer (score 0):

Both conventions are used and you need to be clear about which your book or tool is using. I have the impression that right-to-left is more common, but I could be wrong. Permutations are functions. Presumably when we wish to emphasize the fact that the operation we are performing is function composition, we may be more likely to use the convention that follows function composition: right-to-left. However, if $\Omega$ is a nonempty set and $S_\Omega$ is the set of all permutations on $\Omega$, then $S_\Omega$ is a group under function composition. For abstract groups we often call the operation a product, and we also call the composition of two permutations a product. Since the convention for products (i.e. multiplication) is left to right, we may be more likely to use that convention when we are stressing "groupy-ness". *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote uses the right to left convention, as does *Elements of Modern Algebra* by Gilbert and Gilbert.